# Добавление листов excel с помощью ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby

У меня через форму на сайте формируется книга .xlsx Я хотел бы динамически клонировать в книге листы исходя из данных, которые будут переданы через форму. Например - у меня есть лист под сотрудника. если через форму создали 2 и более сотрудников, то и листов под них должно стать больше. Сами листы уже форматированы и стилизованы определенным способом, который мне сложно повторить с помощью гемов - убил на это кучу времени, ничего не получив... я ищу способ, как мне клонировать определенные листы в книге со всеми стилями и ссылками( имеются ввиду ссылки в rels, в workbook и прочие). думал вызывать vs.net через ruby, но это не катит на unix... подскажите, как лучше поступить?

Comment: Если 50 сотрудников - 50 листов? подход неправильный. Вы же все равно не сможете просматривать более одного листа. Плоская таблица на однм листе. При правильной организации из этой таблицы достаточно просто извлекать нужную информацию,  оперативно просмотривать или массово печатать таблицы каждого сотрудника

Comment: та нет) мне надо именно 50 листов, так как это регистрационная форма и на каждого сотрудника подается отдельный лист. требование законодательства, не моя прихоть)

Comment: Попробуйте повторить форматирование в Google Spreadsheets. Там есть экспорт в xlsx. Клонирование можно будет производить как на REST API или рубишный гем от гугла, так и на Google Apps Script.

Comment: А еще наверное можно макросами обмазаться -- напихать данные в сыром виде на руби, а при открытии эксель их отформатирует.

Comment: @Nakilon, сейчас попробовал импортировать мой файл в гугл, довольно криво импортирует, много данных потерялось... придётся еще покарячиться и всё внести) а гем называется google_drive? или есть еще какой-то?

Comment: Наверное нужно смотреть сюда https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ruby

Comment: @Nakilon спасибо, надо попробовать будет...